# How to properly get a y/n input in C

Tags: c, stdin, getchar

So, I'm a C and programming newcomer and I'm trying to write a function to abstract y/n choices in a program that uses a lot of them, as of now I have it like this:

```
void chooser (char *choice)
{
    while (1)
    {
        *choice='\0';
        *choice=getchar();
        while(getchar()!='\n');

        if(*choice == 'y' || *choice == 'n')
            break;
    }
}
```

The second getchar consumes input in excess in the stdin so that it shouldn't be susceptible to the user typing gibberish.

The only problem is that if I type "ywhatever" or "nwhatever" the first getchar still captures "y" and "n" and passes it to the main.
I would like to have it so that the user has to type "y" or "n" and nothing else.
I could try ditching getchar and switching to fgets for capturing and sscanf for parsing, which is how I prefer to get strings, but, dunno, it's just a single character, I would prefer not to overcomplicate things.

Is there a way to scan stdin after user input to see if it contains more than one alphabetic character?

EDIT:
In the end, I went for this:

```
int chooser ()
{
    char buffer[MAXIN];    

    while (1)
    {
        printf("y/n: ");
        if (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin)!=NULL)
        {   
            if (buffer[0] == 'y' || buffer[0] == 'n')
            {
                if (buffer[1]=='\n')
                {
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    while(getchar()!='\n');
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (buffer[0]=='y')
    {
        return 1;
    }
    if (buffer[0]=='n')
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

It seems to be doing exactly what I need it to do, is there something else I should adjust? Does a fgets from the standard input need a if(fgets(...)!=NULL) check?

Comment: have you tried fgetc ?

Comment: `fgets` returns `NULL` in case if `EOF` encountered or some read error occur. Add check for `NULL`  ->  `if(fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin) != NULL) {..`.

Comment: Okay, thanks, I knew fgets generally needed checking, but in this case it's reading from the user input, so is it still possible for it to encounter reading error? What could I possibly type to make fgets go nuts? :')

Comment: why not have chooser return an int and define YES and NO as constants. Seems much simpler. Your caller has to worry about case, about localization (I know not important for you probably)

Comment: You're right, i think I'll do it like that, so that I can just go " if (chooser()==1) " in the main, I think it's more linear.

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with this solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void chooser(char *choice)
{
  char buffer[200];    
  while (1)
  {
    fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin);        
    if (buffer[0] == 'y' || buffer[0] == 'n')
      break;
  }    
  *choice = buffer[0];
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  while (1)
  {
    char yn;
    chooser(&yn);    
    if (yn == 'y' || yn == 'n')
      printf("User choice: %c\n", yn);
  }
}
```

That's not exactly "overcomplicated"

There is still room for improvement, e.g the EOF condition is not handled at all here.

Example of execution:

```
abc
def
y
User choice: y
n
User choice: n
yes
User choice: y
no
User choice: n
noooo
User choice: n
```

Comment: Nothing, I misclicked ;-) However, is your choice of buffer size arbitrary?

Comment: @BenjaminBarrois yes it is, anyway we want everything after `y` or `n` be discarded.

Comment: If you're going to do it that way, at least have the `chooser` function return a Boolean value. Checking for 'y' or 'n' in two places seems silly to me. Also, `fgets()` is the wrong choice here. Your buffer will overrun if the user types in several characters.

Comment: @BenjaminBarrois actually the buffer size must be 2 at minimum (one for the character and one for the NUL string terminator).

Comment: @JonathanWood no there will be no buffer overrun, the excess characters will be discarded and that's what we want here.

Comment: I think it suffers from the same exact problem: if you type "ydsdcsdcsdcdcdscsdcdsc" the fgets still captures the first character and buffer[0] still equates to "y".

Comment: @symbolwraith yes you are right, actually the buffer size should be larger than what the user is expected to type, e.g. 200 or so. I corrected the program.

Comment: I added a "if (buffer[1]=='\n')" to the conditions needed to break the while and now it sorta does what I wanted now. If you type one character and press Enter you always produce a newline, right?
Now I get onto the buffer overrun protection you proposed, thank you.

Comment: @symbolwraith there won't be any buffer overrun ever here, well give the buffer size to `fgets`.

Comment: Yes, but you can kinda flood the stdin by falling asleep on the keyboard, so that the next fgets execution doesn't actually ask you anything else, it just consumes the remaining characters in the stdin.

Comment: I can use "while(getchar()!='\n');" to consume those remainders but for some reason if I put it after the fgets it requires me to input y twice instead of once before it lets me out of the loop.

EDIT: Oh, nevermind, I think I solved. :)